# Permutations of strings takes too long to solve

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm creating an array of permutated and unique letters in a string, only to sort them alphabetically and find the middle element in the set.

```
def middle_permutation(string)
  length = string.length
  permutation_set = string.split("").permutation(length).to_a.map{|item| item.join}.sort
  permutation_set.length.even? ? permutation_set[(permutation_set.length)/2-1] : permutation_set[(permutation_set.length/2)+1]
end
```

For example:

```
middle_permutation("zxcvbnmasd") should equal "mzxvsndcba"
```

Even for small strings (N >=10), the calculations take pretty long to finish, and I can forget about anything double that; is there a quicker way?

Comment: please, provide example input and expected output.

Comment: Added an example for ya

Comment: Keep in mind there are 3,628,800 permutations for a string of length 10.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a faster way to find the middle permutation? Yes, there is. (Do the strings include repeated characters? If not, it is even easier.)

Comment: @rici An algorithmic approach would be vastly faster, but the built-in `permutation` method does brute-force it.

Comment: The patterns won't change for any given X-length sequence, so you can brute-force these into a look-up table for ordering if you want. A more nuanced approach is to construct that sequence algorithmically.

Comment: @tadman: i certainly didn't claim the answer was incorrect, just that there are faster solutions. How does my comment imply anything else?

Comment: @rici I'm agreeing with you, not disputing your advice. Just an attempt to clarify what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the letters are unique, as in the OP's question.

1. Sort
2. Pluck the middle letter of the sorted string (rounded down). This is the first letter of the middle permutation.
3. If the original list had an even number of letters, the rest of the permutation is the reverse sort of the remaining letters.
4. If not, take the middle letter again. Now the rest of the result is the reverse sort of the remaining letters.

Comment: Yea! Wrote my code above if you wanna check it out. Came to the same kind of reasoning soon after I started looking at the sorted original array with the middle permutation.

Answer (score 1):

The method below returns the desired permutation directly, without iterating through permutations.

The asker has stated that the string contains no duplicated letters, which is a requirement for this method. I assume the characters of the string are sorted. If they are not, the creation of a sorted string would be the first step:

```
str = "ebadc".chars.sort.join
  #=> "abcde"
```

**Code**

```
def mid_perm(str)
  return mid_perm_even_length_strings(str) if str.size.even?
  first_char_index = str.size/2
  str[first_char_index] << mid_perm_even_length_strings(str[0,first_char_index] +
    str[first_char_index+1..-1])
end

def mid_perm_even_length_strings(str)
  first_char_index = str.size/2-1
  str[first_char_index] + (str[0,first_char_index] + str[first_char_index+1..-1]).reverse
end
```

**Examples**

```
mid_perm 'abcd'
  #=> "bdca" 
mid_perm 'abcde'
  #=> "cbeda" 
mid_perm 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
  #=> "mzyxwvutsrqponlkjihgfedcba"
```

**Explanation**

Let's start by defining a method to produce permutations of the letters of a string.

```
def perms(str)
  str.chars.permutation(str.size).map(&:join)
end
```

*Strings containing an even number of characters*

Consider

```
a = perms "abcd"
  #=> ["abcd", "abdc", "acbd", "acdb", "adbc", "adcb",
  #    "bacd", "badc", "bcad", "bcda", "bdac", "bdca",
  #    "cabd", "cadb", "cbad", "cbda", "cdab", "cdba",
  #    "dabc", "dacb", "dbac", "dbca", "dcab", "dcba"]
```

`a` contains `4! #=> 4*3*2 => 24` elements, `4` being the length of the string.

Notice that since the characters in `perms`' argument are sorted, the array returned is also sorted<sup>1</sup>.

```
a == a.sort  #=>true
```

As `a.size #=> 24`, the "middle" element is either `a[11] #=> "bdca"` or `a[12] #=> "cabd"` (where `11 = (24-1)/2` and `12 = 24/2`), depending on how we want to round. The question stipulates that, for even-length strings, we are to round down, so that would be `"bdca"`.

Now let's slice `a` into `str.size` equal arrays, each containing `a.size/str.size #=> 24/4 => 6` elements:

```
b = a.each_slice(a.size/str.size).to_a
  #=> [["abcd", "abdc", "acbd", "acdb", "adbc", "adcb"],
  #    ["bacd", "badc", "bcad", "bcda", "bdac", "bdca"],
  #    ["cabd", "cadb", "cbad", "cbda", "cdab", "cdba"],
  #    ["dabc", "dacb", "dbac", "dbca", "dcab", "dcba"]]
```

The desired element is therefore

```
b[(a.size/str.size-1)/2-1][-1]
  #=> "bdca"
```

This value can be computed more directly as follows.

```
first_char_index = str.size/2-1
  #=> 1 
first_char = str[first_char_index]
  #=> "b" 
remaining_chars = (str[0,first_char_index] + str[first_char_index+1..-1]).reverse
  #=> "dca" 
first_char + remaining_chars
  #=> "bdca"
```

The same logic applies to all strings having an even number of characters. We therefore can write the method `mid_perm_even_length_strings` shown in the *Code* section above.

For example (for a 12-character string)

```
mid_perm_even_length_strings 'abcdefghijkl'
  #=> "flkjihgedcba"
```

*Strings containing an odd number of characters*

Now consider

```
str = "abcde"
a = perms str
  #=> ["abcde", "abced", "abdce", "abdec", "abecd", "abedc",
  #    "acbde", "acbed", "acdbe", "acdeb", "acebd", "acedb",
  #    "adbce", "adbec", "adcbe", "adceb", "adebc", "adecb",
  #    "aebcd", "aebdc", "aecbd", "aecdb", "aedbc", "aedcb",

  #    "bacde", "baced", "badce", "badec", "baecd",..., "bedca",

  #    "cabde", "cabed", "cadbe", "cadeb", "caebd", "caedb",
  #    "cbade", "cbaed", "cbdae", "cbdea", "cbead", "cbeda",
  #    "cdabe", "cdaeb", "cdbae", "cdbea", "cdeab", "cdeba",
  #    "ceabd", "ceadb", "cebad", "cebda", "cedab", "cedba",

  #   "dabce", "dabec", "dacbe", "daceb", "daebc",..., "decba",

  #   "eabcd", "eabdc", "eacbd", "eacdb", "eadbc",..., "edcba"]
```

Here the permutation contains `5! #=> 100` elements, in `5` blocks of `20`. (Again, `a.each_cons(2).all? { |s1,s2| s1 < s2 } #=> true`.)

The middle element of `a` is clearly the middle element of the block of elements that begin with

```
str[str.size/2] #=> "c"
```

That block would be the array

```
b = a.each_slice(a.size/str.size).to_a[str.size/2]
  #=> ["cabde", "cabed", "cadbe", "cadeb", "caebd", "caedb",
  #    "cbade", "cbaed", "cbdae", "cbdea", "cbead", "cbeda",
  #    "cdabe", "cdaeb", "cdbae", "cdbea", "cdeab", "cdeba",
  #    "ceabd", "ceadb", "cebad", "cebda", "cedab", "cedba"]
```

which would be `'c'` plus the middle element of the array

```
["abde", "abed", "adbe", "adeb", "aebd", "aedb",
 "bade", "baed", "bdae", "bdea", "bead", "beda",
 "dabe", "daeb", "dbae", "dbea", "deab", "deba",
 "eabd", "eadb", "ebad", "ebda", "edab", "edba"]
```

That array is merely the permutations of the string `"abde"`. Since that string contains an even number characters, its middle element is

```
mid_perm_even_length_strings 'abde'
  #=> "beda"
```

It follows that the middle element of the permutations of the letters of `"abcde"` is therefore

```
'c' + 'abde'
  #=> "cabde"
```

This clearly applies to all strings containing an odd number of characters.

<sup>1. The doc for [Array#permutation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) states, "The implementation makes no guarantees about the order in which the permutations are yielded.". We therefore might need to tack `.sort` to the end of the operative line of `perms`, but with Ruby v2.4 (and I suspect, earlier versions) that is, in fact not necessary here</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to compact it like this:

```
def middle_permutation(string)
  list = string.chars.permutation.map(&:join).sort

  list[list.length / 2 - (list.length.even? ? 1 : 0)]
end
```

Which yields:

```
middle_permutation('zxcvbnmasd')
# => "mzxvsndcba"
```

Comment: That's the perils of brute-forcing. I'm not sure what the pattern is here: `"a", "ab", "bac", "bdca", "cbeda", "cfedba", "dcgfeba", "dhgfecba", "edihgfcba", "ejihgfdcba"` but that's the "middle" of each set for `abc...`.

Comment: If you can make a function that returns arbitrary permutation M for given string of length N then you could do this in pretty much *O(N)* time for any given string. This reminds me of the [Towers of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) problem.

Comment: The pattern is: (1) If there are an odd number of characters, take the middle one. (2) Take the character just before the middle of the characters (or remaining characters, if one was removed in step 1). (3) sort the remaining characters in reverse order.

Comment: @rici I think you're on to something there. If you can make that into a workable bit of code, that's a much better answer than mine.

Comment: @tadman: it only works if all the characters are distinct, which is why I asked about that. It should be obvious why it works. List permutations in ascending and descending order (as a mind experiment :-) ) Take permutations in matching positions. Note the correspondence between elements.

Comment: I think it'd work regardless since the list is explicitly sorted, unless I'm mistaken. `aaaaaa` is just trivially easy to do, but `aabbcc` should follow the same rules you described, so long as you pre-sort the characters of the string.

Comment: True, it will work if there are the same number of each element. All elements being unique is a special case of that, as are all elements being the same and all elements appearing exactly twice.

Comment: @rici Interesting. I didn't expect that behaviour, but testing it with `aabcddd` produces some really odd results. Presumably this is because multiple permutations that emit the same string are "collapsed" which throws off the effective middle.

Comment: @rici, I implemented your suggestion (slightly modified), though I didn't see your comment until after I posted.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out there are two tracks to this, odd strings and even strings.

For odd strings, you take out the middle character Element of the sorted array and the one before it, in that order. When you do that you have two remaining arrays, the one the right and left, both alphabetically sorted. You tack on elements of the right array, starting with the last element, then do the same for the one on the left.

For even strings, Do the same but only take one character in the first step: the (N/2) element.

Here's my solution:

```
def middle_permutation(string)
  string_array = string.chars.sort

  mid_string = []
  length = string.length
    if length.even? 
      mid_string << string_array[length/2-1]
      string_array.delete_at(length/2-1)
      (mid_string << string_array.reverse).flatten.join
    else 
      mid_string << string_array[(length/2)-1..length/2].reverse
      string_array.slice!((length/2)-1, 2)
     (mid_string << string_array.reverse).flatten.join
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to generate **all** permutations. Just find overall number of permutations as `PN = N!` where N is string (of different chars) length and calculate only needed `PN/2-th` permutation by its number - for example, using [this approach](http://antoinecomeau.blogspot.ru/2014/07/mapping-between-permutations-and.html)

```
     public static int[] perm(int n, int k)  
 {  
      int i, ind, m=k;  
      int[] permuted = new int[n];  
      int[] elems = new int[n];  
      for(i=0;i<n;i++) elems[i]=i;  
      for(i=0;i<n;i++)  
      {  
           ind=m%(n-i);  
           m=m/(n-i);  
           permuted[i]=elems[ind];  
           elems[ind]=elems[n-i-1];  
      }  
      return permuted;  
 }
```